# es6 exported function "not a function"

Tags: javascript

I want to create a library file where I pass in a value and it returns an object that calls a created instance of localforage.

EDITED: simplified code still doesn't work

```
export default function(walkId) {
    var store = localforage.createInstance({
        name: walkId
     });

     var tilesDb = {
        test: 'val'
     };

     return tilesDb;
 }
```

and I import it like this:

```
import getTilesDb from './tilesDb';
```

but when I call it:

```
let tilesDB = getTilesDb(someIdhere);
```

I get an error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I call my function?

Comment: Well you can't call it because it's not a function, that much's obvious :)

Comment: Where are you calling this? Are you importing the correct module? Are these the only two modules? How do you run modules, do you transpile them?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot export an undefined variable. In the way you have written your code, `getTitlesDb` is not defined yet.

There are two possible solutions. The first one is to name your function on the same line as the `export` statement.

```
export default function getTilesDb(walkId) { ... }
```

The second one is to declare the function as a variable and then export the variable.

```
const getTilesDb = function(walkId) { ... }

export default getTilesDb;
```

Comment: In `export default function(walkId) { … }`, there is nothing undefined?

Comment: One actually *can* export undefined variables. They just need to be declared somewhere.